# Video Memory Usage Behavior with WPF

Tags: wpf, video-memory

I am working on a WPF application which renders images on a canvas. When I keep displaying the images in a loop on the canvas, I see that during the first 2 minutes, there is a massive allocation and deallocation of video memory (over 1000 MB). There is a severe jitter in the video getting displayed. The machine has a NVidia Quadro NVS 310 graphics card ( 512 MB). After 2 minutes, the allocations and deallocations of the memory on the video memory is within 300 MB. The jitter is no longer seen and the display is smooth during this time. Suppose, if I pause the application for few seconds and then resume, I again see the video memory going beyond 1000 MB and again the jitter sets in.
[Snapshot of Perforator Video Memory of over 1000MB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NXmYE.png)

My questions are:
1. Why does video memory shoots up beyond 1000 MB when the application is started and resumed after a pause? Does it not use the graphics card memory during this time since it exceeds graphics card memory of 512 MB?
2. Why does the video memory stay within 300 MB after the application runs for 2 minutes?
3. Can we say that the application is using hardware acceleration if the "Video Memory usage" in the perforator tool is within the graphics card memory ( 512MB in this case)?

Comment: If you share a [mcve] someone might be able to reproduce and explain it.

Comment: It seems you have a problem with your code. However, we can't help unless we have [code or information that can reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Otherwise, we are just blindly guessing.